# How do I reward a friendly/helpful user if I am new?

Tags: discussion, chat, down-votes

I am new so I am not allowed to vote.  I am not allowed to chat either.  Chances are all new questions especially from new programmers will get downvoted.  I slept over my question and planned on how to deliver them before I actually posted them so that I know I am actually lost and not lazy.  Nonetheless, I am still downvoted.  I saw some other new posters getting downvoted as well, and at first glance, newer programmers would assume that members here are unfriendly.  I know that is not true.  People with louder voices can be heard more.  Just like anything else, there are some unfriendly-"this guy is so noob he shouldn't be here" kind of people, and there are some really friendly user.  I'd like to thank and reward helpful and friendly members, what options do I have?

Comment: I just realised you can't vote.. All you can do is try to earn enough rep from positive posts. You can post both questions *and* answers, and I'd imagine answers are more likely to earn you rep.

Comment: on your own questions, and answers to your own questions, you can comment. Later, when you have 15 rep, you can come back and vote. And you can get to 15 rep with 7 approved edits.

Answer (score 10):

There really is no shortcut.

You need to work at getting the [upvote privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) which, on this site, arrives at a reputation of 15:

> Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers
>   are most useful and appropriate.

Note that voting is for the posts and not the posters.  A poster who makes useful and appropriate posts will inevitably see their reputation rise, but it is the quality of the post itself that gets the vote.

Don't forget that, as commented by @KateGregory:

> on your own questions, and answers to your own questions, you can
>   comment. Later, when you have 15 rep, you can come back and vote. And
>   you can get to 15 rep with 7 approved edits.